# Overriding the bean defined in parent context in a child context

Tags: spring, architecture, jakarta-ee, multi-tenant

Our app has a requirement to support multi-tenancy. Each of the boarded customer might potentially override 1 or more beans or some properties of a bean defined at the core platform level (common code/definitions). I am wondering what is the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Spring allows you to redefine the same bean name multiple times, and takes the last bean definition processed for a given name to be the one that wins.  So for example, your could have an XML file defining your core beans, and import that in a client-specific XML file, which also redefines some of those beans. It's a bit fragile, though, since there's no mechanism to specifically say "this bean definition is an override".

I've found that the cleanest way to handle this is using the [new `@Bean`-syntax introduced in Spring 3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). Rather than defining beans as XML, you define them in Java. So your core beans would be defined in one `@Bean`-annotated class, and your client configs would subclass that, and override the appropriate beans. This allows you to use standard java `@Override` annotations, explicitly indicating that a given bean definition is being overridden.

Comment: are you sure you can re-define a bean with the same id/name in a child ctx?

Comment: looking at this page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring/topusers I'd think he knows what he's talking about

Comment: thank you. I am not questioning the correctness of his post. I wanted some re-assurance on that particular statement as I have been told by my dev resource that this is not possible in new versions of spring i.e. 2.5.x and later. He tried to re-define the bean (that was defined in parent context) in a child context with the same name and he received an error during startup.

Comment: @Pangea: It logs warnings, yes, but not exceptions. Can you give us an example?

Comment: @skaffman: I have not tried this but was under the impression that it is not possible, can you possibly share an detailed example outlining the process of re-defining the beans ?

Comment: it is possible. instead of discussing this topic here, why don't you just make a simple test as see for yourself? :-P

Comment: Weirdly enough, it did not work for me. To be more specific, when I have resourceServerConfigurer bean defined in ResourceServerConfig, and another resourceServerConfigurer in ResourceServerTestConfig extends ResourceServerConfig, the overriding works, but in a log I get a warning that bean from ResourceServerConfig overrides ResourceServerTestConfig, not vice versa (but debugging shows otherwise). But when I move ResourceServerTestConfig to "test" sources, the config gets created but overriding does not happen, Spring uses bean from ResourceServerConfig.

Comment: Also, I failed to find any indications on how Spring processes inherited Java configs in its manual. Say, "modularized configurations" does not consider this scenario, unlike @Import, nested configurations etc.

Comment: This doesn't work. I was actually under impression that this method works but actually, spring overrides the bean based on the file path (package name + class name) order of configuration file. So basically, just make sure your override configuration file comes after the main file (alphabetically).