# overriding bean configuration in spring

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

Let's say I have two modules. One is core and another is core dependent implementation module.
Core is a jar file for that dependent implementation module war.

In the core I have a bean defined like

```
<bean id="x" class="com.pokuri.X">
 <property name="y" ref="y"/>
 <property name="z" ref="z"/>
</bean>
```

And that class has a method as follows

```
public class X{

  public void doSomeJob(){
   .......
  }   

}
```

this method is being called from some core classes. Now I need to alter the logic in that doSomeJob() method of X as per my core dependent implementation. So, I create a class like this

```
public class ExtX extends X{

  @override
  public void doSomeJob(){
    // changed logic
  }

}
```

and defined the bean with same id in another application context xml file like this.

```
<bean id="x" class="com.pokuri.ExtX">
     <property name="y" ref="y"/>
     <property name="z" ref="z"/>
</bean>
```

and we are building application context using `contextConfigLocation` context parameter in `web.xml` specifying value as `classpath:springfolder`.

But in the core logic I am getting core bean instance only(i.e `X` instance) not `ExtX`. How can we override that bean definition and let system start using new extend bean definition?

And I heard that with same ID in different application context files will override first loaded bean definition with later loaded bean definition. Is there any `priority` kind of attribute on bean definition to let ApplicationContext use highest priority one to consider over low priority one when beans with same ID were found.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way of overriding the bean definition is what you have indicated - to define it with the same id multiple times and the last bean definition with the same id is the one which takes effect. So if you ensure that `ExtX` is the last one loaded up, it should just work, and to ensure this you can do this in your war file, instead of loading up by saying `classpath:springfolder`, you can explicitly import the core configuration in your war's Spring config file and then override the bean this way:

```
<import resource="core-resource.xml"/>
<bean id="x" class="com.pokuri.ExtX">
     <property name="y" ref="y"/>
     <property name="z" ref="z"/>
</bean>
```

This will ensure that your overridden bean is the one which takes effect.

There is no priority/order field that you can make use of here though - if you want you can load up all bean definitions of a type by providing `Map<String,X>` as a parameter, and sort it by expecting an order property and use it that way, but there is lot more work to it.

A second approach is described here: [Overriding the bean defined in parent context in a child context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249978/overriding-the-bean-defined-in-parent-context-in-a-child-context)

Comment: Of course it works. But is it a good practice to cover one definition by another? I think it is kind of hack :/