# Override bean definition in java config

Tags: java, spring

I have a configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfig{
  @Bean
  public FooService fooService() { ... }
  @Bean
  public AbcService abcService() { ... }
}
```

That class is defined in a lib that I can't change. I have a project where `FooService` is used in many places. In my project I have another configuration class

```
@Configuration
@Import({
  FooConfig.class,
   
})
public class BarConfig{
  @Autowired AbcService abc;
  ...    
}
```

`AbcService` is used here because there are services which depends on that service and those services are declared in `BarConfig`. However, `FooService` is not used here(it is used only in controllers)

I need to change the implementation of `FooService`. Can I define new `FooService` bean in `BarConfig`? Will it override already present definition which is imported via `FooConfig`?

Comment: Can you subclass `FooConfig` and then not include it in your context scan?

Comment: it's a bad idea, special hook for only one case. I suggest `BarConfig` to be the root configuration class

Comment: I mean `BarConfig extends FooConfig` with an overriding method. (Or your own `MyFooConfig` and import that instead.)

Comment: I meant `BarConfig extends FooConfig` is a bad idea. What if I have several such `FooConfig`'s?

Answer (score 16):

You can redefine the same bean name multiple times, the spring container will take the last bean definition processed for a given name to be the one that wins.
In your case, as the core project that contains the configuration you can't change does not depend on any of the beans you define in your project, it will work fine if you redefine the `FooService
bean.`
there was lot of answers about how to override bean defintions before, you can have a look to have more informations.

- [overriding bean configuration in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833804/overriding-bean-configuration-in-spring)
- [Overriding the bean defined in parent context in a child context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249978/overriding-the-bean-defined-in-parentA-context-in-a-child-context)
- [Spring's overriding bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849192/springs-overriding-bean)

Comment: I can't change `FooConfig`. What is the id of a `FooService` bean defined there? It is not specified explicitly. If I know the id, I will be able to override it as you described

Comment: With java based config,the method name annotated with `@Bean` works as bean ID.
In your case `fooService` will assume the role of id.